# DjangoCMS - How to cache the whole page?

Tags: python, django, caching, django-cms

I'd like to know if DjangoCMS is able to cache my page out of the box so it only would fetch the database once (right now, it makes a db connection everytime I change or refresh the page).

The main problem is that my website is going to handle a lot of traffic, and would be very expensive to open db connections to serve every page for all users.

Another thing is that this tool is used by big websites like they show here:

Links the made me think it was possible: https://www.django-cms.org/en/case-studies/

http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/how_to/caching.html
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible and controlled through the `CMS_PAGE_CACHE` setting. The following snippet is an example of a Database cache setup. For more information on caches see [Django's cache framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/).

Note that a page that contains CMSPlugins with `cache = False` will not be cached.

```
CMS_PAGE_CACHE = True
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.db.DatabaseCache',
        'LOCATION': 'my_table_name',
        'TIMEOUT': 180,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'MAX_ENTRIES': 200,
            'CULL_FREQUENCY': 2,
        }
    }
}
```